# MiniZinc: slicing an array using changing indices in a for all

Tags: arrays, slice, minizinc

I want to do the following in Minizinc: set a constraint on a slice of an array, taking 7 indices and moving one further each time. I tried doing it this way:

`constraint forall(i in 0..length(schedule)-1 - maxOn) (0 in schedule[i..i+maxOn]);`

Where schedule is my output array of size 64, maxOn is 7 (days). But I get the following error:

`MiniZinc: type error: array comprehension expression cannot be an array.`

Any ideas?

In python I would use a loop with array slicing:

`for i in range(len(schedule) - maxOn):`

`my_slice = schedule[i:i+maxOn]`

Answer (score 0):

The following complete code-sample based on what you wrote works as expected in the latest MiniZinc

```
int: maxOn = 7;

array[0..64] of var int: schedule;

constraint forall(i in 0..length(schedule)-1 - maxOn) (
    0 in schedule[i..i+maxOn]
);
```